# sql Properly grouping my table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access in order to play around with tables through SQL. I want to properly group my table and this is an example of what I want to do. Say I have a table like this:

```
Cool?  |  Age
 Yes   |  15
 No    |  34
 No    |  12
 Yes   |  26 
 Yes   |  10
```

What I want is the resulting table to show how many ppl are cool or not grouped by age. For instance in this example it would be:

```
 AGE  |   Count that are cool  | Count that is Not cool

 <25  |          2             |           1

 >=25 |          1             |           1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
case when age<25 then '<25' when age>=25 then '>=25' end as age, count(case when age<25 then 1 else null end) as [Count that are cool], count(case when age>=25 then 1 else null end) as [Count that is Not cool]
    from Table1
    group by case when age<25 then '<25' when age>=25 then '>=25' end
```